# Separating a directed graph into two subgraphs such that their cumulative weight is minimized

Tags: arrays, string, graph-theory, distance, shortest-path

I have been stuck with this problem for some time now, so any suggestions would be appreciated

I'm trying to separate a fully connected directed weighted graph into two subgraphs with minimal cumulative weight. But this seems computationally infeasible with 10^5 number of nodes.

The problem from which this originated:
We are given a string and our task is to find the shortest path to type that string with two fingers on a keyboard. At the beggining our fingers are positioned as we choose.
Then for every letter you can type it with any of two fingers.
The distance between two keys is a manhattan distance between them.
Keyboard looks like this:
qwertyuiop
asdfghjkl
zxcvbnm
With keys positioned in a square grid.
So the shortest distance from q to a is 1, from q to s is 2 and from p to n is 6.
Strings consist only of letters.
Solution should work with strings of length < 10^5

Thanks again for any ideas

I tried a greedy approach but it didn't work because the best starting position of the second finger depends on what letters are further in the string.

Then I reformulated the problem to separating a fully connected directed weighted graph into two subgraphs with minimal cumulative weight. But this approach seems computationally infeasible.

Comment: Cumulative?  What does this mean? The sum of the edge weights in both subgraphs?  That would mean you want to delete the edges with the greatest weights.

Comment: You need the sum of the weights of the edges that are required by the string to be typed.  ( if the letter pair 'qs' is not present, the weight of that edge is irrelevant )  Perhaps that is what you mean by "cumulative"?

Comment: https://twitter.com/engineers_feed/status/1650963842745135131

Comment: So the problem with deleting edges in fully connected graph is that it’s impossible to built one with the maximum size of the string and constraints on time and memory. So there should be a solution without building fully connected graph. It might also be that my approach is wrong

Comment: Are you sure that the problem requires splitting the graph into two sub-graphs? If at time T1, your fingers are on "a" and "h" and you want to type "g" as the next character then the shortest path is from "h" to "g"; but, if at time T2, your fingers are on "f" and "l" and you want to type a "g" then the shortest path is from "f" to "g". If you really want the minimum cost then splitting the letters into disconnected sub-graphs may preclude a more optimal solution where the sub-graphs of the finger movements overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Divide keyboard into left and right.

```
qwert    yuiop
asdfg    hjkl
zxc      vbnm
```

Assign finger 1 to first letter in string that appears on left

Assign finger 2 to first letter in string that appears on right

Construct path that keeps fingers on their initially assigned side

" hello world"

```
finger 1 : e w r d
finger 2 : h l l o o l
```

Comment: It's not optimal. e.g. "agh" would yield ag + h, where the ag edge is expensive, vs a + gh.

Comment: I think the greedy approach wont work, since we need the full information and it’s incomplete until we reach the end of the string. To answer your previous question: yes, cumulative means “the sum of all edges in resulting graphs”.

Comment: Please edit you question.  Do not hide important clarification in comments.

Answer (score 0):

As a frame challenge to the question, don't split the graph into two disconnected components where each finger types all the letters in exactly one of those components.

Instead, work only on a sub-string window of the input string and use look-ahead to calculate the minimum distance for all possible combinations of the next `n` finger movements and pick the optimum next move for the look-ahead window based on the minimum total distance for the entire look-ahead window.

For example:

- If you have your fingers on `k` and `a` and need to type the word `plush` then the optimum minimum distance may be to type `pluh` with the right finger and `s` with the left finger;
- However, if you have your fingers on `f` and `p` and need to type the word `there` then the optimum minimum distance may be to type `there` entirely with the left finger.

In both cases you need to type the letter `h` but the optimum finger to use depends on your current finger position and the upcoming letters.

---

You can calculate the distances using a binary tree of either moving the left or right finger to the next letter in the string and maintain the tree to depth `n` (where `n` is the size of the look-ahead) and:

- pick the branch at the root with the minimal total depth;
- discard the other branch;
- calculate the new leaf nodes for the new `n`th character in the look-ahead window; and
- repeat.

---

In Python:

```python
from typing import Dict, List, Optional, Tuple

class Key:
    def __init__(
        self,
        ch: str,
        x: int,
        y: int
    ) -> None:
        self.ch = ch
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def distance(self, key: "Key") -> int:
        return abs(self.x - key.x) + abs(self.y - key.y)

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, ch: str) -> "Key":
        if ch not in keyMap:
            raise AttributeError(f"Invalid key: {ch}")
        return keyMap[ch]


keyMap: Dict[str,Key] = {
    "q": Key("q",  0, 0),
    "w": Key("w",  1, 0),
    "e": Key("e",  2, 0),
    "r": Key("r",  3, 0),
    "t": Key("t",  4, 0),
    "y": Key("y",  5, 0),
    "u": Key("u",  6, 0),
    "i": Key("i",  7, 0),
    "o": Key("o",  8, 0),
    "p": Key("p",  9, 0),
    "a": Key("a",  0, 1),
    "s": Key("s",  1, 1),
    "d": Key("d",  2, 1),
    "f": Key("f",  3, 1),
    "g": Key("g",  4, 1),
    "h": Key("h",  5, 1),
    "j": Key("j",  6, 1),
    "k": Key("k",  7, 1),
    "l": Key("l",  8, 1),
    "z": Key("z",  0, 2),
    "x": Key("x",  1, 2),
    "c": Key("c",  2, 2),
    "v": Key("v",  3, 2),
    "b": Key("b",  4, 2),
    "n": Key("n",  5, 2),
    "m": Key("m",  6, 2),
}

class KeyState:
    left: Key
    right: Key
    previous: "Optional[KeyState]"
    children: "Optional[Tuple[KeyState, KeyState]]"
    distance: int
    is_left: bool
    child_distances: Tuple[int,int]

    def __init__(
        self,
        left: Key,
        right: Key,
        previous: "Optional[KeyState]",
        is_left: bool,
    ) -> None:
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.previous = previous
        self.children = None
        self.child_distances = (0, 0)
        if self.previous is None:
            self.distance = 0
            self.is_left = is_left
        elif is_left:
            assert self.right == self.previous.right, "Should have the same right keys"
            self.distance = self.left.distance(self.previous.left)
            self.is_left = True
        else:
            self.distance = self.right.distance(self.previous.right)
            self.is_left = False

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "L" if self.is_left else "R"

    def generate_children(
        self,
        key: Key
    ) -> None:
        if self.children is None:
            self.children = (
                KeyState(key, self.right, self, True),
                KeyState(self.left, key, self, False),
            )
            self.child_distances = (
                self.children[0].distance,
                self.children[1].distance,
            )
        else:
            assert self.children[0].left == key
            assert self.children[1].right == key
    
    def generate_descendants(
        self,
        value: str
    ) -> None:
        if value == "":
            return
        ch, rest = value[0], value[1:]
        key = Key.get(ch)
        self.generate_children(key)
        left, right = self.children
        left.generate_descendants(rest)
        right.generate_descendants(rest)
        self.child_distances = (
            left.distance + min(left.child_distances),
            right.distance + min(right.child_distances)
        )
    
    def path(self) -> str:
        return f"{self}({self.child_distances[0]}, )"

def find_fingers(
    value: str,
    search_depth: int,
) -> str:
    if value == "":
        return ""

    initial_state: List[KeyState] = []
    key1 = Key.get(value[0])

    # Find all possible second start characters up to the seach depth.
    second_chs = {c for c in value[1:search_depth] if c != value[0]}
    # If there are no other characters up to the search depth, generate all characters.
    if not second_chs:
        second_chs = {c for c in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" if c != value[0]}

    for ch in second_chs:
        key2 = Key.get(ch)
        if key1.x <= key2.x:
            state = KeyState(key1, key2, None, True)
        else:
            state = KeyState(key2, key1, None, False)
        state.generate_descendants(value[1:search_depth+1])
        initial_state.append(state)

    # Find the optimal start state.
    state = min(initial_state, key=lambda ks: min(ks.child_distances))

    distance = 0
    start_fingers = f"{state.left.ch}{state.right.ch}"
    response = []
    i = 1

    while state is not None:
        distance += state.distance
        response.append(str(state))
        search_window = value[i:i+search_depth]
        assert len(search_window) <= search_depth
        state.generate_descendants(search_window)
        l_dist, r_dist = state.child_distances
        if state.children is not None:
            state = state.children[0] if l_dist <= r_dist else state.children[1]
        else:
            state = None
        if state is not None:
            if state.previous is not None:
                state.previous.children = None
                state.previous = None
        i += 1

    return f"{start_fingers}: {''.join(response)} = {distance}"
```

Then if you call it for the string `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` with a look-ahead windows of 3, 7, 10 and 15 characters:

```python
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
print(f"  : {alphabet}")
print(find_fingers(alphabet, 3))
print(find_fingers(alphabet, 7))
print(find_fingers(alphabet, 10))
print(find_fingers(alphabet, 15))
```

Outputs:

```
  : abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
ab: LRRRRRRRRRRRLLRRLRLRRRLLRL = 56
ab: LRRRRRRRLRLLRRLLLRLRRLLLRL = 52
ab: LRRLLRRRLRLLRRLLLRLRRLLLRL = 50
ai: LLLLLLLLRLRRLLRRLRLRRLLLRL = 49
```

The output is the keys the left- and right-fingers start on followed by the fingers used to press the next key in the sequence and, finally, the total distance.

You can see that as the look-ahead window increases, better solutions are found (but the execution time increases).

Then if you call it for the string `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` with a look-ahead windows of 3, 7, 10 and 15 characters:

```python
print(f"  : {alphabet*2}")
print(find_fingers(alphabet*2, 3))
print(find_fingers(alphabet*2, 7))
print(find_fingers(alphabet*2, 10))
print(find_fingers(alphabet*2, 15))
```

Then the output is:

```
  : abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
ab: LRRRRRRRRRRRLLRRLRLRRRLLRLLRRRRRRRRRRRLLRRLRLRRRLLRL = 116
ab: LRRRRRRRLRLLRRLLLRLRRLLLRLLRRRRRRRLRLLRRLLLRLRRLLLRL = 108
ab: LRRLLRRRLRLLRRLLLRLRRLLLRLLLLLLLLLRLRRLLRRLRLRRLLLRL = 102
ai: LLLLLLLLRLRRLLRRLRLRRLLLRLLLLLLLLLRLRRLLRRLRLRRLLLRL = 101
```

Again, this shows that the distance travelled improves as the look-ahead window increases. However, this time, with a look-ahead window of 10 characters (3rd line) you can see that the characters `bcfgh` are pressed with the right-finger initially and then on the second pass through the alphabet are pressed with the left-finger.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried a similar approach, the problem with it is that the number of root nodes grows exponentially, just like in a binary tree. And special cases can be constructed that require the window to be as large as a string. The worst case, however, needs to be quadratic or better in complexity. That is the main problem of greedy approaches

Comment: As an example, imagine string “aqwsderfp”; in such a string you only know that placing the second finger at “p” is best at the very end.

Comment: @DaniaRepublic The root nodes will never grow exponentially; you will have one finger on the first character of the string and the other finger on a different character and these pairs of characters make the root nodes; since your alphabet has 26 letters then there can be at most 25 root nodes. When you want to explore the graph then you can either move the left finger or the right finger so you can generate a complete set of all solutions as 25 binary trees of depth equal to the length of the string and then pick the minimum distance from all those trees and you have an optimal solution.

Comment: This answer will implement that if you set the search window to equal the length of the string (for long strings, it will take a very long time to run and will probably run out of memory but if you have a system with enough resources and time then it would give you an optimal solution).